# How can I get the path from a file

Tags: android

I'm making an App where I call the file explorer, the when I choose a file i get the name with `file.getName()` and put it in a TextView and get the path with `file..getPath()` and save it in a String, this String I use it to attach the file into a mail... my problem is that when a choose a file like .PDF, .DOC, .DOCX, .MP3 I can attach it but when a select an image I get this kind of path: "/media/external/images/media/1220" and does not attach anithing, I've been serarching everywhere and use almost every option I have found with no result.

Here is my code:

```
    private void PickFile(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKER);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == PICKER)) {
       String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
        File file = new File(FilePath);
    }
    if (txtAdjunto1.getText() == "_") {
        adjunto1 = file.getPath();// I get the path to add it to the MimeBodyPart
        txtAdjunto1.setText(file.getName());// I put the name in the TextView
```

I've been trying this:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
Cursor cursor = null;
int column_index;
String ruta = null;

try {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null){

        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ruta = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return ruta;

} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

But the app crashes when I pick the file.
Also tried this:

```
file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

But still geting this "/media/external/images/media/1220"...
Hop someone can help me with this, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` allow the user to choose a piece of content. That content *might* be a local file. That content might also be:

- Something on a file server on the network
- Something in a cloud storage service, such as Google Drive
- Something in an encrypted volume
- Something that *is* a file, but is not a file that you can access directly
- And so on

You have two main options. If you *only* want *files*, then use [a third-party file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) to replace all of the code in your question.

Or, you can take the `Uri` that you get from `data.getData()` in `onActivityResult()` and do two things with it:

- First, use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` object pointing to that `Uri`. You can call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a "display name" for the content, which should be something that the user will recognize.
- Then, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get at the content itself, similar to how you might use a `FileInputStream` to get at the bytes in a file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, well I did almost everithing you told, 'ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT' throws me a message that I don't have an app to handle this action... tried using 'DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()' but the app crashes at the moment I pick a file.ContentResolver same... only choice left is using a third party file chooser library that is the next option... I'll be posting my results with it...

Comment: @GilbertoPenaloza: " 'ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT' throws me a message that I don't have an app to handle this action" -- that should be available on Android 4.4+, but not older versions. "tried using 'DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()' but the app crashes at the moment I pick a file" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: I finally made it using a third party file chooser as you told me, and I think it was the best, the app looks awesome like this... thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

The following code is to select any type of file from **file manager** and **camera** then **convert to byte array** and attach file make edit as per your requirement

```
private void selectFile() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Choose from File Manager",
                "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ComposeActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Attachment!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = Constant.checkPermission(ComposeActivity.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Camera";//String
                    if (result)
                        cameraIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from File Manager")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Choose from File Manager";//String
                    if (result) {
                        FileManagerIntent();
                    }
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

to call camera

```
private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
```

file from file manager

```
private void FileManagerIntent() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 111);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

results

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }
```

getting camera result and converting it to bytearray

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(destination);
        String uriString = uri.toString();

        String path = destination.getAbsolutePath();

        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = ComposeActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    strFileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            strFileName = destination.getName();
        }

        attachLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtFileName.setText(strFileName);

        try {
            fileByteArray = bytes.toByteArray();

            strFile = Base64.encodeToString(fileByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.v("Soma", strFile);
            Log.v("Byte Array * ", strFile);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

result from file manager

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri.toString().contains("video") || uri.toString().contains("audio")) {
            Toast.makeText(ComposeActivity.this, "Oops! can't send video/audio file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = ComposeActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        strFileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                strFileName = myFile.getName();
            }

            Log.v("Super DisplayName", strFileName);
            attachLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtFileName.setText(strFileName);

            try {
                InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                fileByteArray = getBytes(iStream);

                strFile = Base64.encodeToString(fileByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

                Log.v("Byte Array * ", strFile);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

file to bytearray

```
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've been trying using this code but it crashes the app, so I took a piece and ended with the 'onSelectFromGalleryResult' until ' } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                strFileName = myFile.getName();
            }' till this line because the rest give me error, and finally get the real file name, still mising the path. Maybe I've been trying too much and I'm blocked but I can't see how to get the path... any sugestion?